# Can I use SecureSocial for calls from say an mobile app

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, securesocial

I have a play 2 application that uses SecureSocial for authentication and it works perfectly. 
I now want to make calls to these rest services on the play application from outside the web app.

Can I for example have an android application use the same secured rest methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FortyTwo team have a post in their engineering blog which clearly explains the steps in a detailed example: http://eng.42go.com/mobile-auth-with-play-and-securesocial/.